# How to use Autofac with WCF fileless activation and a custom ServiceHostFactory?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I need to add binding/configuration in my CusotmServiceHostFactory. However, I would like to use Autofac. How can my CustomServiceHostFacotry implement AutofacServiceHostFactory? I'm using fileless activation so my config section looks like this:

```
<serviceActivations>                
  <add service="Project.Business.Services.AccountService" 
        relativeAddress="Account/AccountService.svc" 
        factory="Project.WebHost.CustomServiceHostFactory"/>
</serviceActivations>
```

Here is my current custom factory:

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IDataContextAsync>();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Repository<>)).As(typeof (IRepositoryAsync<>));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
                i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));

        var container = builder.Build();
        var host = new CustomServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        Type contractType = GetContractType(serviceType);
        host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(contractType, container);

        return host;
    }
    private static Type GetContractType(Type serviceType)
    {
        return serviceType.GetInterfaces()
            .FirstOrDefault(i => Attribute.IsDefined(i, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false));
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is nowhere I set the AutfoacServiceHostFactory.Container property. I've tried changing my CustomServiceHostFactory to implement AutofacServiceHostFactory like so:

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : AutofacServiceHostFactory
```

..but no matter what I do, when I publish to IIS and browse the service I get this error:

> The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before
>   services can be instantiated.

---

**Edit 1:** I've also tried this.

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : AutofacServiceHostFactory
```

Then assigning to the container. My original code changes slightly here:

```
AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
var host = new CustomServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
Type contractType = GetContractType(serviceType);
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(contractType, AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container);
```

This gives the same error. In fact, when I run on localhost I no longer even get into the CreateServiceHost method when debugging. The browser just renders the error. Is that not the proper entry point / composition root anymore?

---

**Edit 2:** Turns out this will work but is rather annoying. I HAVE to override this CreateServiceHost method with the string constructorString as a parameter. If I try to override the other method signature (that takes the Type serviceType parameter) I never hit my breakpoint in that method... no idea why. This seems like a hack. Why don't I ever get into the CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType... override?

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : AutofacServiceHostFactory
{
    public CustomServiceHostFactory()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IDataContextAsync>();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
                i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));

        Container = builder.Build();
    }

    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        Type serviceType = GetType(constructorString);
        Type contractType = GetContractType(serviceType);
        var host = new CustomServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(contractType, Container);

        return host;
    }

    private static Type GetContractType(Type serviceType)
    {
        return serviceType.GetInterfaces()
            .FirstOrDefault(i => Attribute.IsDefined(i, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false));
    }

    private static Type GetType(string typeName)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null) return type;

        foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = a.GetType(typeName);
            if (type != null)
                return type;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign the ServiceHost.Container property? `host.Container =  builder.Build();` ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question to show what I tried.

Comment: So you also set it on `host.Container` or just on `AutoServiceHostFactory`?

Comment: There is no host.Container. I only have a container when I implement AutofacServiceHostFactory and try to assign to its container. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No sorry.. was my fault. Have you seen the [autofac documentation sample](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html) ?

Comment: Yes, most specifically here. http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html#svc-less-services. That doesn't address where the var builder = new ContainerBuilder() code block should be placed. Also my ServiceActivations section needs to point to MyCustomServiceHost factory, not the AutfacServiceHostFactory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, finally got this working. I hope this can help someone else. Here is the CustomServiceHostFactory:

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    public CustomServiceHostFactory()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IDataContextAsync>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWorkAsync>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
                i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        Type contractType = GetContractType(serviceType);
        var host = new CustomServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(contractType, AutofacHostFactory.Container);

        return host;
    }

    private static Type GetContractType(Type serviceType)
    {
        return serviceType.GetInterfaces()
            .FirstOrDefault(i => Attribute.IsDefined(i, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false));
    }
}
```

Here is the CustomServiceHost code (implementation omitted for brevity):

```
public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{        
    public CustomServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
    }

    protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
    {
        base.ApplyConfiguration();
        AddServiceDebugBehavior();
        AddWcfMessageLoggingBehavior();
        AddGlobalErrorHandlingBehavior();
        AddServiceCredentialBehavior();
        AddEndpoints();
        ConfigureThrottling();
    }

     //implement above methods here...
}
```

Here is the config (section that matters):

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <!-- where virtual .svc files are defined -->
  <serviceActivations>                
    <add service="Project.Business.Services.AccountClassService" 
          relativeAddress="Account/AccountClassService.svc" 
          factory="Project.WebHost.CustomServiceHostFactory"/>

    <add service="Project.Business.Services.UserService"
          relativeAddress="User/UserService.svc"
          factory="Project.WebHost.CustomServiceHostFactory"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Each of my WCF services has this behavior attribute to make them function per call (instead of PerSession which is the default):

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall
```